# I am trying to drop multiple pins on a map view but getting error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.businessArray.count; i++) {
        Business *business = [self.businessArray objectAtIndex:i];
        MapAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init]; 
        NSLog(@"%f %f", business.coordinate.latitude, business.coordinate.longitude);
        mapAnnotation.title = business.name;
        mapAnnotation.subtitle = business.address1;
        mapAnnotation.coordinate = business.coordinate;
        [bMapView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];
        NSLog(@"ti %@", mapAnnotation.title);
        NSLog(@"sub %@", mapAnnotation.subtitle);
        NSLog(@"coo %f %f", mapAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, mapAnnotation.coordinate.longitude);
    }

- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView;

    if (annotation != mapView.userLocation) {
        static NSString *defauleID = @"myLocation";
        //        pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defauleID];
        if (pinView == nil) {
            pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier:defauleID];
        }
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;

        UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        [rightButton setTitle:annotation.title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [rightButton addTarget:self 
                        action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;
    }

    return pinView;
}
```

error:
An instance 0x1cdd97b0 of class MapAnnotation was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked, and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger. Here's the current observation info:
 (
 Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1cd97a30>

Answer (score 0):

Release the annotation every time inside the loop

```
    for (int i = 0; i < self.businessArray.count; i++) {
            Business *business = [self.businessArray objectAtIndex:i];
            MapAnnotation *mapAnnotation = [[MapAnnotation alloc] init]; 
            NSLog(@"%f %f", business.coordinate.latitude, business.coordinate.longitude);
            mapAnnotation.title = business.name;
            mapAnnotation.subtitle = business.address1;
            mapAnnotation.coordinate = business.coordinate;
            NSLog(@"ti %@", mapAnnotation.title);
            NSLog(@"sub %@", mapAnnotation.subtitle);
            NSLog(@"coo %f %f", mapAnnotation.coordinate.latitude, mapAnnotation.coordinate.longitude);
            [bMapView addAnnotation:mapAnnotation];
            [mapAnnotation release];
        }
```

Comment: I use ARC. However, I solved it using [bMapView mapAnnotations: arrayOfAnnotations];

Answer (score 0):

i think you have receiving a notification by adding the observer.. and when you received that notification and execute the function associated with that observer deallocating your MapAnnotation but you are not removing that observer please remove observer too in dealloc...

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultSenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Hope this will help you..